# LISTAGG gave error "not a GROUP BY expression"

Tags: oracle, listagg

I am trying to add a text field, a.desc to a working Oracle query using LISTAGG.  Can someone please help on resolving this syntax error?

I have 3 tables
1) Table A

```
id  |  Name      |   Desc     |  
1   |  Name_A_1  |  Desc_A_1  |  
2   |  Name_A_2  |  Desc_A_2  |  
3   |  Name_A_3  |  Desc_A_3  |
```

2) Table B

```
id  |  Name      |   Desc     |  
11  |  Name_B_11 |  Desc_B_11 |  
12  |  Name_B_12 |  Desc_B_12 |  
13  |  Name_B_13 |  Desc_B_13 |
```

3) Table C

```
id  | Table_A_id  | Table_B_id  |  
1   |    1        |     11      |  
2   |    1        |     12      |  
3   |    1        |     13      |  
4   |    3        |     12      |  
5   |    3        |     13      |
```

- Here is what is working with current output

```
A id | A Name   |  B id(s)   |  
  1  | Name_A_1 | 11; 12; 13 |  
  3  | Name_A_3 | 12; 13     |
```

```
Select A.id AS "A id", A.Name AS "A Name",
       LISTAGG(C.id,'; ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY A.id) AS "B id(s)"
From Table_A A
     INNER JOIN Table_C C ON A.id = C.id
     INNER JOIN Table_B B ON B.id = C.id
GROUP BY A.id, A.Name
ORDER BY A.id
```

- Here is the first desired output by adding "A Desc" column:
  A id | A Name   |  A Desc  |  B id(s)   |
  1  | Name_A_1 | Desc_A_1 | 11; 12; 13 |
  3  | Name_A_3 | Desc_A_3 | 12; 13     |

```
Select A.id AS "A id", A.Name AS "A Name", A.Desc AS "A Desc",
       LISTAGG(C.id,'; ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY A.id) AS "B id(s)"
From Table_A A
     INNER JOIN Table_C C ON A.id = C.id
     INNER JOIN Table_B B ON B.id = C.id
GROUP BY A.id, A.Name, A.Desc
ORDER BY A.id
```

** I am receiving the error of **"not a GROUP BY expression"**

- Here is the second desired output(with Name_B_#) added in last column:

```
A id | A Name   |  A Desc  |  B id(s)   |  
  1  | Name_A_1 | Desc_A_1 | 11(Name_B_11); 12(Name_B_12); 13(Name_B_13) |  
  3  | Name_A_3 | Desc_A_3 | 12(Name_B_12); 13(Name_B_13)                |
```

I haven't got this far, got stuck on the query above.  This section I want to add the Table B desc to each B.id.

thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the below query and it works with your sample data

```
    Select A.id1 AS "A id", A.Name1 AS "A Name", A.Desc1 AS "A Desc",
    LISTAGG(C.Table_B_id,'; ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY A.id1) AS "B id(s)"
    From  A
    INNER JOIN  C ON A.id1 = C.Table_A_id
    INNER JOIN  B ON B.id1 = C.Table_B_id
    GROUP BY A.id1, A.Name1, A.Desc1
    ORDER BY A.id1
```

The answer for your second question below

```
   Select A.id1 AS "A id", A.Name1 AS "A Name", A.Desc1 AS "A Desc",
   LISTAGG(C.Table_B_id||'('||B.Name1||')','; ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY 
   A.id1) AS "B id(s)"
   From  A
   INNER JOIN  C ON A.id1 = C.Table_A_id
   INNER JOIN  B ON B.id1 = C.Table_B_id
   GROUP BY A.id1, A.Name1, A.Desc1
   ORDER BY A.id1
```

Comment: Hi psaraj12, thank you for checking the query is correct. I resolved the 2nd issue using TO_CHAR(A.Desc) because the data had hidden HTML tags/datatype.  So it caused the error.

Comment: Hi Xin H i have answered your second question as well